# I didn't fill out my direct deposit in time for my first paycheck: what will happen?

Tags: salary

I was just rehired by a company I had previously worked for. I was not required to fill out another W-4, and did not even give a thought to direct deposit, as no one mentioned it being required. In the span of about six months that I was not employed at the company, I forgot much of the process for entering time information and viewing my paycheck online. Long story short, by the time the first pay period ended, I was able to enter my time on my time card online, but did not set up direct deposit; my previous direct deposit info had been removed. I am working in Massachusetts, which does not require employers to offer a physical check.

Just today I set up my direct deposit, but it is too late for the previous pay period. Will I be paid for the previous pay period, along with the current pay period, when the current pay period ends? Or is it a standard practice to still send a check? I'm assuming just not paying me isn't a legal option.

Comment: I'm guessing calling HR and asking would have taken you less time than to write out this question.... :D

Comment: The likely answer is that you will get a physical check for this pay period.  However, only your HR or payroll department will know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to talk to your employer about this.  Sounds like a bad onboarding process.  Even if you worked there before, you normally would still have paperwork to fill out.  Of course you will be paid since you did the work, but it may be delayed.  You'll only find out by talking to them.